# React Routes Not working on Heroku, but Are working Locally

Tags: reactjs, heroku, routes, local

This question has been answered a million times by others, but so far nothing seems to work.  Most of the answers included code for a server.js file.  My app, which has a backend of Ruby on Rails and Frontend with JavaScript and React, doesn't have a server.js file.  My question is, should it have one to fix the problem of routes not working on Heroku but working locally?  And if not, how can this problem be fixed?  It's frustrating should I need to create a server.js file when everything works perfectly when I navigate to the other routes with links (just not when I go directly to the url) but of course if I need to I will.  I just never learned about this file until now.

App.js below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import Articles from './components/Articles'
import Home from './components/Home'
import NotFound from './components/NotFound'
import NavBar from './components/Navbar'
import ChessBoard from './components/chess/ChessBoard'
import Info from './components/Info'
import './App.scss'

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return <div className="app">
      <div className="router">
      <Router>
        <NavBar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/articles' exact component={Articles} />
        <Route path='/chess' exact component={ChessBoard} />
        <Route path='/info' exact component={Info} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    </div>
    </div>
  }
}

export default App
```

And, I added a static.json file, with and without the clean_urls setting.

```
{
    "root": "build/",
    "routes": {
      "/**": "index.html"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, router working in development mode and not working in production mode is caused by wrong use of `publicPath` (or basepath in some build tools).

You have given me so little information that I can only make subjective guesses

Your frontend work in local just because it is served at `/`, not work in remote server, because it is served under a base path such as `/app`.
In most build tools, default basepath is `/`.

If you are using webpack, use [publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) setting.

Update: Since you are using React-router, use [basename](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/StaticRouter/basename-string).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not using webpack.  That all makes sense to me.  Having never done this before, question is, where should I edit the basepath?  You've provided me a great answer with webpack, but I've never used that either.  Going into it, I kind of thought Heroku would take care of this but I'm wondering should I install something like webpack instead?  I'm not sure what other relevant information I can provide but I'm happy to try.

Comment: The key is how your frontend to be served in the remote server. In other words, is there any prefix in the final url. Perhaps you can use a environment variable to store the prefix, and put it in front of all your root path.